# Bootstrap col-sm-* not applying to tablet

Tags: bootstrap-4

I am using the Bootstrap V4.1.2 framework, and am experiencing the col-sm-* class not applying on tablet... meaning it's collapsing on tablet when it shouldn't be.  See my code below.

Thank you in advance for any/all guidance!

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6 col-lg-3"> <a href="#"><img src="assets/img/cattle-herdsires.jpg" alt="Herd Sires" class="img-fluid"/></a>
      <p><a href="#" class="btn btn-primary" role="button">Herd Sires</a></p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6 col-lg-3"> <a href="#"><img src="assets/img/cattle-2yearoldbulls.jpg" alt="2-Year Old Bulls" class="img-fluid"/></a>
      <p><a href="#" class="btn btn-primary" role="button">2-Year Old Bulls</a></p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6 col-lg-3"> <a href="#"><img src="assets/img/cattle-yearlingbulls.jpg" alt="Yearling Bulls" class="img-fluid"/></a>
      <p><a href="#" class="btn btn-primary" role="button">Yearling Bulls</a></p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6 col-lg-3"> <a href="#"><img src="assets/img/cattle-females.jpg" alt="Females" class="img-fluid"/></a>
      <p><a href="#" class="btn btn-primary" role="button">Females</a></p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: 4 x col-sm-6 = 24 cols cells and the maximum cells in a row are 12 (IIRC).

Comment: Thank you Niloct!  If I split the 1 row into 2 rows, the same issue applies?  col-sm-6 doesn't display as 2 cols on tablet no matter what I try?  I'm looking to display a row of 2 cols on tablet (sm and up) and 4 cols on desktop (lg and up).

Comment: Are you sure the viewport size is  ≥576px ?  You could always just use col-6 vs col-sm-6 which will work for even smaller screens.

Comment: @Niloct Having extra columns is fine since they're all in a single `row`; they extra ones will automatically move into a new row once they exceed 12. @ffossay are you able to reproduce this in a snippet anywhere (Bootply, JSFiddle, Codepen, etc)? See https://jsfiddle.net/u7w4exkn/ for an example; I get 2 columns on small without issue.

Comment: Thank you @TimLewis ... although I have a Codepen account, I've never submitted a pen... lol.  I'm not seeing 2 columns on small (tablet)... rather I'm seeing 4 columns (at 50% width) stacked vertically?  Mobile (xs) and Desktop (lg, xl) are displaying as intended... however Tablet (sm, md) is not displaying as intended?

Comment: What do you mean `4 columns (at 50% width) stacked vertically`? On `sm`, I see 2 columns with 2 rows each (due to the way I explained that having extra columns in a single `row` works)

Comment: My apologies @TimLewis ... to better explain, this is what I'm seeing:  MOBILE: 1 col of 4 images at 100% div width, TABLET: 1 col of 4 images at 50% div width, DESKTOP: 4 cols of 4 images at 25% div width.  MOBILE (xs; default) and DESKTOP (lg, xl) are behaving as desired.  The TABLET (sm, md) however is not, and should be displaying 2 cols of 4 images at 50% div width)... which is not what I'm seeing/experiencing.  This better clarify?  Thank you for your patience and support!

Comment: The tablet's width might not be enough to trigger the `sm` breakpoint, and instead is displaying `xs` (1 column, 4 images). If you rotate it, can you see `sm` (2 columns, 2 images each) or even `lg` (4 columns, 1 image each)?

Comment: Thank you @TimLewis -- both tablet portrait and landscape are displaying 1 col of 4 images -- portrait at 50% width, and landscape at 25% width.  For the life of me can't figure out why?  I am testing on an iPad Mini.